# Is this the correct way to determine if a date range ends in less than a year from when it begins in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I am working through the [Friendly Date Ranges](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/friendly-date-ranges) challenge on FreeCodeCamp :) Essentially there are 3 conditions which should be checked before the function begins:

> Do not display information that is redundant or that can be inferred
>   by the user: *if the date range ends in less than a year from when it
>   begins, do not display the ending year.*

But as I am reading further, the wording of the next condition seems confusing.

> Additionally, if the date range begins in the *current year* and ends
>   within one year, the year should not be displayed at the *beginning* of
>   the friendly range.

And finally:

> If the range ends in the same month that it begins, do not display the
>   ending year or month.

So I am thinking when the array gets passed to the function:

```
makeFriendlyDates(["2016-07-01", "2016-07-04"])
```

I'd go about it like this:

```
var newarr,
    newarr1 = arr[0].split('-'), // ['2016', '07', '01']
    newarr2 = arr[1].split('-'), // ['2016', '07', '04']
    date1 = new Date(newarr1), // Fri Jul 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
    date2 = new Date(newarr2), // Mon Jul 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
    _date1 = new Date(date1); // Fri Jul 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
    date1.setFullYear(date1.getFullYear() + 1); // Sat Jul 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

**UPDATE 5/23/2016**

I've decided to pair this down as narrow the focus to what's not working and where I am having difficulty.

They're two problems I am having:
One is I am not sure my logic is matching up with the requirements:

```
    if (date2 < date1) {
        newarr2.shift();
        if ((date2 < date1) && (date2 < _date1)) {
            newarr1.shift();

        } else if ((date2.getMonth()) === (date1.getMonth())) {
            newarr2.splice(0, 2);
        }
    }
```

And I am not sure how I would concat the values from the splicing so the format looks like the following:

```
 ["July 1st, 2016", "July 4th, 2018"]
```

Basically my question is are my conditions correct and how I would get the correct output required.

```js
function makeFriendlyDates(arr) {
    var newarr,
        newarr1 = arr[0].split('-'), // ['2016', '07', '01']
        newarr2 = arr[1].split('-'), // ['2016', '07', '04']
        date1 = new Date(newarr1), // Fri Jul 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
        date2 = new Date(newarr2), // Mon Jul 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
        _date1 = new Date(date1); // Fri Jul 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
    date1.setFullYear(date1.getFullYear() + 1); // Sat Jul 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)


    function dateTransMogrifier(arr) {
        var newarr = [],
            month = function(b) {

                var monthName = {

                    '01': 'January',
                    '02': 'February',
                    '03': 'March',
                    '04': 'April',
                    '05': 'May',
                    '06': 'June',
                    '07': 'July',
                    '08': 'August',
                    '09': 'September',
                    '10': 'October',
                    '11': 'November',
                    '12': 'December',
                    'month': function(mn) {
                        return this[mn];
                    }
                };
                return monthName.month(b);
            },

            monthDate = function(c) {
                c = parseInt(c);
                var dateSuffix = {

                    'st': 'st',
                    'nd': 'nd',
                    'rd': 'rd',
                    'th': 'th',
                    'date': function(ds) {
                        return this[ds];
                    }
                };

                if (c === 1) {

                    return c + (dateSuffix.date('st'));

                } else if ((c === 2) || (c === 22)) {

                    return c + (dateSuffix.date('nd'));

                } else if ((c === 3) || (c === 23)) {

                    return c + (dateSuffix.date('rd'));

                } else if ((c > 3) || (c < 22) || (c > 24)) {

                    return c + (dateSuffix.date('th'));

                }

            };

        newarr.push(arr[0]);
        newarr.push(month(arr[1]));
        newarr.push(monthDate(arr[2]));

        return newarr;
    }

    newarr1 = dateTransMogrifier(newarr1);
    newarr2 = dateTransMogrifier(newarr2);

    if (date2 < date1) {
        newarr2.shift();
        if ((date2 < date1) && (date2 < _date1)) {
            newarr1.shift();

        } else if ((date2.getMonth()) === (date1.getMonth())) {
            newarr2.splice(0, 2);
        }
    }
    newarr = newarr1.concat(newarr2);
    return newarr;

}


makeFriendlyDates(['2016-07-01', '2016-07-04']);
```

Comment: You haven't received any answers because you haven't asked a question. You need to specify some inputs, expected output, actual output and any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the two dates, the result will be the difference in milliseconds which you can convert to years:

```
differenceInMillis = Math.abs(new Date("2016-07-01") - new Date("2017-07-02"));

function millisecondsToYears(millis) {
  millisecondsPerYear = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
  return millis/millisecondsPerYear;
}

millisecondsToYears(differenceInMillis) > 1
```

Since your dates appear to be in ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DD), you can simply parse them directly using `Date.new`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll have to try your solution. Do you have any ideas how the output would be like so ` ["July 1st, 2016", "July 4th, 2018"]`?

Comment: As long as all your strings conform to that format, use a regex to match and remove the ordinal suffix: `datestring.replace(/(st, )|(nd, )|(rd, )|(th, )/, ", ")`. Then parse it like above using `new Date()`.